# ¿Cómo hago un árbol binario de búsqueda de nombres en pascal?

Tags: pascal, árboles-binarios

El árbol tiene que estar ordenado por nombre, pero no sé como compararlos para ver si un nombre que quiero agregar es mayor o menor.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: El procedimiento de búsqueda es si es sencillo, aquí están los pasos que debe seguir: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAsqueda_binaria#Procedimiento. Lo siguiente es que intentes implementarlo y si te salen dudas o problemas los preguntes aquí siguiendo las indicaciones que te han dado anteriormente en cuanto a las preguntas. concretando más lo que necesitas y dando detalles más concrets.